# Most efficient inter-process communication on Ubuntu

Tags: tcp, pipe, ipc

I have a C++ simulation running on my server. At the same time there is C# based code which is mainly used for statistics collection. The logs that are generated by the C++ code is formatted and consumed by C# code. The two programs run on the same machine.
I refer to the simulation generating logs as "producer" and the other process which formats the logs as "consumer".

There are multiple copies of the producer that run in the system. In fact upto 20 producers can run in the system at the same time. There is just one copy of the consumer. The producer logs have unique IDs which identifies which simulation the log is coming from.

Assuming that I have large amount of memory available, what is the best method for the producers and the consumer to communicate?

At this moment each producer can generate upto 100MBps logs. So highest amount of logs that will be produced is going to be 2GBps. I suspect the consumer may not be able to absorb that much throughput and may fall behind the producers. I want to make sure that the producers are not going to get back-pressure if the consumer is not fast enough. I assume I have enough memory to absorb unprocessed logs.

I'm not sure what are my (best) options here. For the problem I have at hand, I'd like to find a flexible method of communication which is 1) Fast enough, 2) Can take care of many producer, single consumer environment, 3) Can leverage large amount of memory without needing to back-pressure the producers, 4) Provides simple APIs so that I don't have to deal with detailed of communication e.g mutexing the shared resources, etc.

Answer (score 0):

- Does your use-case really demand a high performance producer-consumer configuration? I would first focus on getting it right before getting it fast.
- As far as getting it right: How are you planning to implement this? What language / technologies do you plan to use? This is less about being on Ubuntu and more about how it is implemented.
- There are many producer-consumer examples available. Its THE classic case of interprocess comunication.

So, identify how you will implement it, find some examples of shared memory solutions vs. message passing, and try! Get it right, then you can make a more informed decision on which is better for your particular use-case.

I suppose others are not quick to answer your question since there is just not one method of interprocess communication that is superior to others. Especially when the question is asked in isolation - with no larger context of what the larger application is for. What are all these logs for?

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I added the important info you mentioned in the original question I asked.